# Hausdorff spaces and convergence

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

How can I construct a filterbase converging to two points in in a non-Hausdorff space?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: First construct a sequence converging to two different points in some non-Hausdorff space. That sequence is a net. Build a filter base from it the way I did in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/308185/12042) to one of your earlier questions.

One handy non-Hausdorff space is any infinite set (e.g., $\Bbb N$) with the [cofinite topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology): **every** non-trivial sequence then converges to **every** point of the space!

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be a non-Hausdorff space. This means that there exist 2 points $p$ and $q$ such that for all neighbourhoods $U$ of $x$ and for all neighbourhoods $V$ of $y$ we have $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$. This is just the logical negation of the Hausdorff condition.

Now define $\mathcal{B} = \left\{U \cap V: U \mbox{ a neighbourhood of } p, V \mbox{ a neighbourhood of } q \right\}$. By the choice of $p$ and $q$, all sets in $\mathcal{B}$ are non-empty, and it's easy to check it is indeed a filterbase (as neighbourhood systems are themselves filterbases), and as we can choose $U = X$ or $V = X$ in particular, e.g., it's clear that $\mathcal{B}$ contains the complete neighbourhood system of both $p$ and $q$, which just means, by definition, that $\mathcal{B} \rightarrow p$ and $\mathcal{B} \rightarrow q$, as required.

Comment: So basically $\mathcal{B} = \{B_i \mid B_i = X \cap V_i(q);  i \in I\}$ ?

Comment: If we fix $U=X$, then how do we show that for *every* $U(p)$, there exists $B_i \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $B_i \subset U(p)$

Comment: @Fatsho a) I'm not sure what the index set $I$ is. We just take the set of *all* intersections of *all* neighbourhoods of $p$ and *all* neighbourhoods of $q$. All of these are non-empty by the choice of $p$ and $q$. In particular, we can take $X$ for the neighbourhood of $p$, so all neighbourhoods of $q$ are in this collection. We can also take $X$ as a nbh. for $q$ so all neighborhoods of $p$ are also in this collection.