# Which are more standard: Filterbases or nets? What are the benefits of each?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, filters, nets

In the text Topology by James Dugundji there are a lot of impressively short proofs (Ex. Tychonoff. Chap. XI Theorem 1.4(4)) using filterbases that later, when I go to class, take an eternity to prove using nets (in class we are using nets). I've never found a proof become simpler once one uses nets instead of filterbases which leads to my first question:

> *Why would anyone ever use nets instead of filterbases?*

My second question has to do with popularity of the concepts:

> *Which is used more often; filterbases or nets?*

Again, the text I use uses filterbases, in class we use nets, if you look for a proof of Tychonoff's theorem, it seems that most use nets (even though, with filterbases, its a three-liner), and there is no tag on MSE for filterbases. Currently, I use filterbases exclusively unless it is something I have to hand to my professor (say, homework. This is due to the fact that we haven't touched on filterbases in class). Should I switch to nets? should I keep using only filterbases? should I do my best to learn both?

Comment: Nets are nice because we can pretend they're sequences, and a lot of people have really good intuition for how sequences "should" work. Filters are nice because they're incredibly efficient ways of unifying multiple notions of convergence. My guess is that the analysts prefer nets and the algebraists prefer filters (at least, this has been my experience) for basically this reason. It's worth noting too that a lot of computer-formalization has been done in the language of filters. See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hhOPRaR3tx0), for instance.

Comment: I would say from a pure topological point, filters are more general, and, once you get used to it, better to deal with. For instance, the standard book of Engelking clearly prefers filters. As far as I know, most proofs of Tychonoff theorem are based upon filters. What makes them so easy is the concept and existence of ultrafilters, though. I'm not aware of an analogue concept for nets.

Comment: (continued from the above due to length restriction.) On the other hand, calculations are most often better done with nets, for instance in topological groups. As an example, it's a two-liner to proof the following with nets: *if a T2 topological group contains a dense, abelian subgroup, it is itself abelian.* I doubt that this can so easily be proven with filters. So, I would recommend to stay familiar with both, filters and nets.

Comment: My experience is that actually the best thing to use is a hybrid of filters and nets described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1568548/where-has-this-common-generalization-of-nets-and-filters-been-written-down?noredirect=1&lq=1).  This avoids all the nasty technicalities of nets while preserving the advantage of being an indexed set (which, for instance, keeps all the calculational advantages that Ulli describes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically the concept of *net* appeared earlier than the concept of *filterbase*. Quotation from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics)):

> Filters on sets were introduced by Henri Cartan in 1937 and [...] they were subsequently used by Nicolas Bourbaki in their book Topologie Générale as an alternative to the related notion of a net developed in 1922 by E. H. Moore and Herman L. Smith.

Both concepts are equally well adequate to introduce the concept of *convergence in topological spaces*.

The concept of *net* is an obvious generalization of the concept of *sequence* (which is one of the most  basic concepts in calculus), and in my opinion it is more intuitive than that of *filterbase*. Nets which are more general than sequences occur quite naturally in calculus, for example when the Riemann integral is introduced. See my answer to [What is the motivation for sequences to be defined on natural numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3770753)

Also Dugundji starts with sequences ands nets in his chapter "Convergence". At the end of section X.1 he says

[image]

That is, the concept of a *filterbase* is an abstraction of that of a *net*. It is a very useful abstraction as you have outlined in your question, and frequently it allows to give short and elegant proofs. Your question

> *Why would anyone ever use nets instead of filterbases?*

suggests that you think that filterbases are superior to nets. This has already been discussed in this forum. See for example

- [Filters vs nets in topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455660/filters-vs-nets-in-topology)
- [Nets and filterbases and convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308173/nets-and-filterbases-and-convergence)
- [isomorphism filter and nets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3720579/isomorphism-filter-and-nets)
- [Where has this common generalization of nets and filters been written down?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1568548/where-has-this-common-generalization-of-nets-and-filters-been-written-down)

Both concepts are equivalent. To some extent it is a matter of taste whether one works with filterbases or nets. You should know both concepts which gives you the flexibility to use more than one tool. And be aware the nets do occur in calculus, replacing them by filterbases would be hard work and lead to a less intuitive approach.

> *Which is used more often; filterbases or nets?*

This is difficult to answer. But a search in this forum gives the following results:

- [[general-topology] net](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgeneral-topology%5D+net)  : 1156 hits
- [filterbase](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=filterbase) : 54 hits

This suggest that nets are still more popular than filterbases. Whether this is true also in the literature is not known to me. But a search in Google Scholar gives at least an indication:

- [net convergence topology](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?hl=de&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=net+convergence+topology&btnG=) : 433000 hits
- [filterbase topology](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?hl=de&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=filterbase+topology&btnG=) : 4940 hits

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would have never imagine nets where that more popular than filter bases. I add the following in case it is useful to someone else: $T_a=\{b\in D\mid a\geq b\}$ where $D$ is a directed set.