# Topology: Basic Queston re: Moore-Smith Convergence

Tags: general-topology

I am currently studying three classic topology books: (1) "Introduction To Topology" (Gamelin & Greene, 1975), (2) (same title by Bert Mendelson, 1958), and (3) "General Topology" (John Kelley, 1955). Of these, only the latter by Kelley even mentions the term Moore-Smith Convergence, also covering related topics such as directed sets and nets. An entire chapter is dedicated to these concepts. Since the other books don't even them at all, I'm wondering if perhaps the teaching approach has shifted over time and now the same basic ideas are adequately addressed through a combination of Cauchy Sequences, sequential and uniform convergence,and function spaces. Am I on track with this thinking or not? If not, why do Moore-Smith Convergence and related concepts seem to be rather neglected as of late?

Comment: A quick round of googling seems to indicate that Moore-Smith sequences and nets are the same thing, and therefore presumably Moore-Smith _convergence_ is just convergence of nets. Perhaps part of the answer is then that people simply have dropped the name Moore-Smith sequence/convergence and talk about nets nowadays (cf. Bredon's Topology and Geometry for a basic treatment).

Comment: If this is true, then it's also worthy to note that the main use of nets in general topology textbooks is to prove Tychonov's theorem; but this use has largely been supplanted by a proof using ultrafilters due to Bourbaki. Either way, one should note that none of Cauchy Sequences, sequential and uniform convergence, and/or function spaces offer a replacement.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4465787.

Comment: If you can find a copy, Schechter, *Handbook of Analysis and its Foundations* has extensive discussion of the relationship between Moore-closure, nets, convergence structures etc., and the way the subject has developed historically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of a general understanding of Moore-Smith convergence as a whole, this motto may help:
A net is what we need
instead of a sequence,
when we are dealing with a topological space
instead of a metric space.
(Not meant literally, just a gloss, so to speak.)

Gemignani, "Elementary Topology", 1967, introduces this subject with the proposition that if A is a subset of a metric space X, then a point in X is in the closure of A, if and only if there is a sequence in A converging to the point.  He then gives an example of a subset of a topological space where a point in the closure is not the limit of any sequence in the set.  Eventually he shows that if A is a subset of a topological space X, then a point is in the closure of A if and only if there is a net in A converging to the point.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think it did get to the essence of what I was looking for, namely when and where to go with Moore-Smith convergence by way of a directed set vs. a standard sequence with domain N. Though I realize there are some exceptions (i.e. in some cases Moore-Smith convergence occurs with numerical domains) I will follow your advice until I learn more by just considering sequential convergence as associated with metric spaces and Moore-Smith/nets/directed sets as associated with open sets in general topological spaces. A very helpful simplification!